# Listening to $emit in vue js and use value in a handler along with parent's value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello Everyone I am listening to $emit and I need to use the value in a handler with another value from the parent component.

**Child Component**

```js
this.$emit("savedInfo", this.savedInfo)
```

**Parent Component**

```html
<v-col v-for="(info, index) in allMyInfo" :key="index">
  <child-component
    v-if="info !== ''"
    @savedInfo="handleSavedInfo(savedInfo, index)"
  />
</v-col>
```

**Parent Component Script**

```js
handleSavedInfo(savedInfo, index){
  console.log(savedInfo) // undefined
  console.log(index) // 1
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's intentional, but you have you're missing a quote/have an extra quote in the child component tag

Comment: FYI, try not to use camel-cased event names. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: @JonathanS. thanks I just removed it.

Comment: @phil thank you for the heads up

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this question before (still trying to find the duplicate) but the answer was to use an arrow function. Something like `@saved-info="savedInfo => handleSavedInfo(savedInfo, index)"`

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much sir

Comment: Do you really want to do it this way? Vue reactivity and double binding wants to liberate you from having to worry about when things happen. This complicated pattern suggests to me that you've gone too far with state in Vue components, and you're trying to do too much with events. Up to you!